# How to echo line out of gzip compressed file?

Tags: mysql, gzip

While importing a mysqldump into a Galera cluster get an error message refering to duplicate error, referencing a line.

How do I echo out the particilar line in order to check the source table?

Import:

```
zcat DB_150909.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p test
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 2412: Duplicate entry '329610-2011-03-27 03:00:00' for key 'user_id'
```

Comment: Why not use `zgrep` to find both the first and the offending duplicate entry?

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
zcat DB_150909.sql.gz | sed '2412q;d'
```

Comment: I agree with the principal but would this cause problems if --extened-insert had been used ?

Comment: No, @iain, that's not a problem, because the line number in the error will be the actual line number from the file, as determined by counting newlines (not statements).  It could be up to a megabyte long with `--extended-insert` but it should be the correct line number.